# how to calculate node variance from igraph object in R?

Tags: r, igraph

I want to calculate standard variance analysis by taking the edge weight between two nodes to identify the most different nodes in the network. I could look at the degree of the node to see the hubs or most central nodes, but my interest is to identify nodes based on edge weight incident to a given node. I thought variance analysis might help me. I would appreciate any ideas you may add.

See the codes below:

```
# Create a graph object

library(igraph)
g = structure(list(from = c(5L, 5L, 5L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 4L, 4L,2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L), 
to = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 5L, 4L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 5L, 1L, 4L, 3L, 5L, 1L, 4L, 2L), 
               weight = c(runif(18, -1,1))), 
          row.names = c(NA, -18L), 
          class = "data.frame")
g = graph_from_data_frame(g)

# varaince 
variances_node <- sapply(V(g), function(x) {var(incident(g,x))}) %>%
  data.frame() %>%
  tibble::rownames_to_column() %>%
  setNames(c("letter","variance"))  %>%
  dplyr::arrange(desc(variance))
head(variances_node)
```

Comment: How are you doing the calculation manually? What value are you expecting for this sample input? Maybe you meant `sapply(V(g), function(x) {var(incident(g,x)$weight)})` since your current code isn't using the edge weights at all.

Comment: What do you mean when you say "the variance of a node"? This is not standard terminology for network analysis. Can you explain the concept you want to compute in plain English, without resorting to code?

Comment: @Szabolcs, sorry about my English. I want to calculate standard variance analysis to identify the most different nodes considering the edge weight as the input value. I could look at the degree of the node to see the hubs or most central nodes, but my interest is to identify those nodes based on their edge weights.  Then, I thought variance analysis might help me. I would appreciate any ideas you may add.

Comment: OK, so you want to take each vertex, and calculate the variance of the weights of its incident edges? If so, please add this information to the body of the post (instead of only in a comment).

Comment: Regarding the language. The `variance of each node in the graph` is not defined. Therefore, describe in your native language how to perform the manual calculation. Translate that to English (using the appropriate online tool) and then back to your native language. Repeat this cycle until the result in the original language seems reasonable. If so, chances are your English is also acceptable.

Comment: Note names are in random order: `vertex_attr(g)` gives `[1] "5" "1" "4" "2" "3"` for attribute `$name`.